# Pyinstaller can't find the png image in the folder

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When I try to open main.exe it says "Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception: No file 'Python/Program Folder/image.png' found in working directory

The image is there, but pyinstaller can't find it while it's looking at the right place.

Comment: What is your working directory?

Comment: C:\Users\levia\Desktop\Progi

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you can see, your file is not in your working directory:) you can either place the `image.png` in the working directory (i.e. `C:\Users\levia\Desktop\Progi`), or [change your working directory](https://linuxize.com/post/python-get-change-current-working-directory/#:%7E:text=the%20running%20script.-,Changing%20the%20Current%20Working%20Directory%20in%20Python,use%20the%20chdir()%20method.&text=The%20method%20accepts%20one%20argument,can%20be%20absolute%20or%20relative.).